# Magento 2 Data Migrattion Tools ignores map.xml

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I have installed migration tool and it is running, but I want to ignore some tables. So I set some  to map.xml but something is wrong - ignore list is beeing ignored

```
<config xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../config.xsd">
<steps mode="settings">
    <step title="Settings Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Settings\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Settings\Data</data>
    </step>
    <step title="Stores Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Stores\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Stores\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Stores\Volume</volume>
    </step>
</steps>
<steps mode="data">
    <step title="Data Integrity Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\DataIntegrity\Integrity</integrity>
    </step>
    <step title="EAV Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Eav\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Eav\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Eav\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Customer\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Customer\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Map Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Map\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Map\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Url Rewrite Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\UrlRewrite\Version191to2000</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Log Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Log\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Log\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Ratings Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Ratings\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Ratings\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Ratings\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="ConfigurablePrices step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\ConfigurablePrices\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="OrderGrids Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Tier Price Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\TierPrice\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Inventory Step">
        <integrity>Migration\Step\Inventory\Integrity</integrity>
        <data>Migration\Step\Inventory\Data</data>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Inventory\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="PostProcessing Step">
        <data>Migration\Step\PostProcessing\Data</data>
    </step>
</steps>
<steps mode="delta">
    <step title="Customer Attributes Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\Customer\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Customer\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Map Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\Map\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Map\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Log Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\Log\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Log\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="OrderGrids Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\OrderGrids\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="SalesIncrement Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\SalesIncrement\Volume</volume>
    </step>
    <step title="Inventory Step">
        <delta>Migration\Step\Inventory\Delta</delta>
        <volume>Migration\Step\Inventory\Volume</volume>
    </step>
</steps>
<source>
    <database host="localhost" name="aa" user="bb" password="cc" />
</source>
<destination>
    <database host="localhost" name="xx" user="yyy" password="zz" />
</destination>
<options>
    <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/map.xml</map_file>
    <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-eav.xml.dist</eav_map_file>
    <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-document-groups.xml.dist</eav_document_groups_file>
    <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist</eav_attribute_groups_file>
    <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-log.xml.dist</log_map_file>
    <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/log-document-groups.xml.dist</log_document_groups_file>
    <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/settings.xml.dist</settings_map_file>
    <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-customer.xml.dist</customer_map_file>
    <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-document-groups.xml.dist</customer_document_groups_file>
    <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-attribute-groups.xml.dist</customer_attribute_groups_file>
    <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/deltalog.xml.dist</delta_document_groups_file>
    <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/order-grids-document-groups.xml.dist</order_grids_document_groups_file>
    <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-document-groups.xml.dist</map_document_groups>
    <class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml.dist</class_map>
    <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-tier-price.xml.dist</tier_price_map_file>
    <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-stores.xml.dist</stores_map_file>
    <!--
    In case bulk_size=0 it will be auto-detected for every document.
    -->
    <bulk_size>0</bulk_size>
    <!--
    Set direct_document_copy = 1 for better performance.
    NOTE: 'source' and 'destination' databases MUST be placed on the same MySQL instance
    and 'destination' user MUST be granted with 'SELECT' permissions on 'source' database
     -->
    <direct_document_copy>1</direct_document_copy>
    <source_prefix />
    <dest_prefix />
    <auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>0</auto_resolve_urlrewrite_duplicates>
    <log_file>migration.log</log_file>
    <progress_bar_format>%percent%% [%bar%] Remaining Time: %remaining%</progress_bar_format>
    <upgrade_customer_password_hash>1</upgrade_customer_password_hash>
    <edition_migrate>opensource-to-opensource</edition_migrate>
    <edition_number>1.8.1.0</edition_number>
    <init_statements_source>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_source>
    <init_statements_destination>SET NAMES utf8;</init_statements_destination>
    <crypt_key>cccccccccccccccccccc</crypt_key>
</options>
```

and map.xml

```
<map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../map.xsd">
<source>
    <document_rules>
        <ignore>
            <document>cms_block</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
             <document>cms_block_store</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
             <document>cms_page</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
             <document>cms_page_store</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
             <document>core_config_data</document>
        </ignore>           
    </document_rules>

</source>
<destination>
    <document_rules>
        <ignore>
            <document>cms_block</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
             <document>cms_block_store</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
             <document>cms_page</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
             <document>cms_page_store</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
             <document>core_config_data</document>
        </ignore>
    </document_rules>
</destination>
```

hope somebody can help to make it work, thanks!
Martin

Comment: have you mapped map.xml?

Comment: how do I map the map.xml - I only addes <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/map.xml</map_file> to config.xml to <options> section? Is there something else to do?

Comment: let me know the commands you are using in cli

Comment: php bin/magento migrate:settings -r vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/config.xml
and
php bin/magento migrate:data -r -a vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.8.1.0/config.xml

Comment: Can you please check with removing the core table skiping code?

Comment: which one is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.2/map.xml.dist
```

**Rename This File To `map.xml`**

> **In Your config.xml file Chnage this :-**
>
> **From :-**
>
> `<map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.2/map.xml.dist</map_file>`
>
> **To :-**
>
> `<map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.2/map.xml</map_file>`

**In Your map.xml File Just Add Table Which You Want to Ignore under the `source` `document_rules` Tag**

```
<source>
    <document_rules>
        <ignore>
            <document>cms_block</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
             <document>cms_block_store</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
             <document>cms_page</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
             <document>cms_page_store</document>
        </ignore>
        <ignore>
             <document>core_config_data</document>
        </ignore>           
    </document_rules>
</source>
```

**No Other Changes In Map.xml File Just Add Your Table**

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the config.xml and map.xml with default migration file.